# Disable photos in maps

Tags: ios, iphone, maps

The Maps app on the iPhone shows the photos from a business's Yelp page, but for some businesses these photos are inappropriate. Is there a way to block them?

Comment: As far as I can tell, @tubedogg's answer (below) is correct.  I would also recommend [providing feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback) and let them know about your concern.  I'm totally with you on this issue and I'll be letting Apple know, too.

Answer (score 1):

No, switching to another mapping program would be the only option.